# Changing >= to <= causes query to exceed execution time limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a query that checks inventory for `vehicles` that have not been seen in a week but that are not listed in the `sold_vehicles` table.

If I run this query:

```
  SELECT all_vehicles.Vin
  FROM all_vehicles
  LEFT JOIN sold_vehicles
    ON all_vehicles.Vin = sold_vehicles.Vin
  WHERE
    sold_vehicles.id IS NULL        AND
    all_vehicles.last_seen >= 1502672069
  ORDER BY all_vehicles.id ASC
  LIMIT 1000
```

Everything works fine.

However, if I reverse the `>=` to `<=` it exceeds the 120 second execution time limit. Why would reversing this behave this way? Any reason other than a lot of results to return, and wouldn't the limit fix that?

To be clear, this is nearly the exact same query, but with `<=` and a `LIMIT 10` yet fails to execute:

```
  SELECT all_vehicles.Vin
  FROM all_vehicles
  LEFT JOIN sold_vehicles
    ON all_vehicles.Vin = sold_vehicles.Vin
  WHERE
    sold_vehicles.id IS NULL        AND
    all_vehicles.last_seen <= 1502672069
  ORDER BY all_vehicles.id ASC
  LIMIT 10
```

Any ideas? Is it amount of results found alone? How do I fix it other than `LIMIT`?

Comment: It could be that no records match, so the query still scans the entire table.

Comment: Check your index coverage. Check `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by removing the `order by`.  Does this return anything?

```
SELECT av.Vin
FROM all_vehicles av LEFT JOIN
     sold_vehicles sv
     ON av.Vin = sv.Vin
WHERE sv.id IS NULL AND
      av.last_seen <= 1502672069
--ORDER BY av.id ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Then, I would create indexes on `all_vehicles(last_seen, Vin, id)` and `sold_vehicles(Vin, id)`.